# Best adhesive for reinstalling this wall tile

Tags: bathroom, shower, tile, exterior

[image]
The grout lines still match up; I just need a good adhesive to put back on. I don’t want to scrapes old mortar or grout out if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Get some of the Loctite Power Grab construction adhesive.

[image]

This stuff grabs pretty good but you'll need to clamp it, prop it up, or duct tape it in place until the adhesive hardens, Good luck

Comment: I second that. I use this product quite a bit.

Comment: I have used it also, the grout may not match up as well but it will be stuck after curing.+